# How much does it cost to advertise here?

Tags: support

Yes here. Ask Different apple exchange.

This is the only place I can think of where I can buy traffic visited by and only by mac owners.

Comment: The [link for ad info](http://stackexchange.com/about/contact) says "To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at ads@stackexchange.com, call +1 (212)232-8280 and select option "2" at the auto-attendant to reach our ad sales team. Our business hours are Monday through Friday, 9am to 5pm Eastern time zone in the United States."

Comment: Lots of non-Mac owners ask here about iPhone, iPod, iPad, iTunes, Apple TV.

Comment: Ah not suitable then. Also I talked to the guy. Minimum advertising is $5k. I wonder if there is any better place to market to mac users only. Is this a relevant question for ask different?

Comment: @JimThio Macworld magazine, Although I'd guess their minimum is probably up there.

Answer (score 1):

Like any shopping question, prices often can change.

The best answer is to just talk to a sales person at these contact points. Ad sales is at the bottom of the page.

http://stackexchange.com/about/contact